# Sublime Text environment variables not present

Tags: python, plugins, environment-variables, sublimetext3, pipenv

I have installed `yapf` and the `PyYapf` package (https://github.com/jason-kane/PyYapf) for sublime text for Python code formatting.
Furthermore, for my Python projects I'm using `pipenv`.

When executing the formatting command in sublime I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/bin/pipenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/_unicodefun.py", line 124, in _verify_python3_env
    ' mitigation steps.' + extra
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Consult https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/python3/ for mitigation steps.

This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended.
You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the
following environment variables:

    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I have now tried the suggestion to use the two above exports and set them globally in my profile (and reboot).
Opening a terminal and checking they seem to be available:

```
$printenv | grep "C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
LANG=C.UTF-8
```

However, sublime text still gives the original error. Looking at the source of the package the environment is read in like this inside the `PyYapf.py` package:

```
self.popen_env = os.environ.copy()
```

When printing the content of `self.popen_env` then the `LANG` and `LC_ALL` don't seem to be set or not to the `C.UTF-8` value.

Where is sublime text getting the envs from?

Comment: Are you on Linux or MacOS?

Comment: I'm on Linux MInt 19

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `os.environ()` should be giving you the environment of the running process directly. I'd suggest a restart to make sure that the dock/launcher inherits the new environment, but you already did that. Do you get different results if you launch Sublime from a terminal (after verifying the vars as above)?

Comment: I'm always running sublime from a terminal, so that should give it the same vars as I receive with `printenv` in the terminal, or not?

Comment: I would assume so. I've had similar problems in the past with these very variables, and setting them in a terminal and launching from there worked while the launcher icon didn't.

Comment: But the question is then, where does sublime get the variables get from...

Comment: `os.environ()` is from the Python runtime, so wherever that gets them. DId you try `import os; print(os.environ)` from the Sublime console as an extra verification of what Sublime sees versus what the plugin sees? You probably want to do it right from a clean start of Sublime, since it's possible for plugin code to permanently modify the environment of the process.

Comment: I've tried it; started a new sublime session from a terminal and executed `import os` and `os.environ` in it, the results I get there vary from the ones that I get when executing `printenv` in the same terminal I used to open sublime with

Answer (score 4):

Quick workaround:

```
$ cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
$ mkdir -p Default
$ echo 'import os; os.environ["LC_ALL"] = os.environ["LANG"] = "C.UTF-8"' > Default/echo.py
```

**Well, for God's sake, DO NOT try this nasty hack. Please take some time to setup your locales properly, otherwise you will likely encounter more locale problems in the future.**

For Linux Mint & other Debian variants, simply run `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and tick off `en_US.UTF-8` (or any other locale that you prefer) on the list. Follow [these](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2017/06/18/unix-locales-vs-unicode/) two [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117608/changing-locale) for more details about locale errors.